# SharePoint2010 creating/updating a site programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a share point site that I wish to update programmatically. I.E I want to add a column in a list. I want to capture this in code so that I can run it against dev, test and live. What is the best way to do this.

Comment: When do you want your code to run? IE: do you want your code to add a column in a list when the site is created, when the list is created, when a user switches on a feature, when an item is added to a list, etc?

Comment: When a feature is switched on it should make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Using Visual Studio 2010, create a Feature and add a Feature Activated event handler.

here's a tutorial on MSDN on how to add a field to a list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa540133.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I hope the best way is to use powershell script and execute the script on any environment.

Another way is you can create wsp package with ListInstance xml.

I prefer the last choice for writing code in feature activation for creating list.
You can refer to my blog for [Creating Custom List with powershell](http://adicodes.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/create-custome-list-with-powershell-in-sharepoint-2010/).